# show context menu of jsTree plugin on user defined events

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, jstree

I followed http://www.jstree.com/demo/ to add a tree view. It works perfectly fine.

However i have a requirement to display the context menu not on the right click but on some other events. Each node contains an arrow and upon clicking that arrow, the context menu should be displayed. Does anybody have any idea on how to access the context menu of jsTree plugin and show it on our own defined events?

Comment: which events you mean? pls explain it more

Comment: Hi @daremachine, I need to place a button next to each node and  show the context menu of jstree on click of that button

Comment: Take a look at this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083636/jstree-custom-node-markup/30095916?noredirect=1#comment48305181_30095916

Comment: Hi @vakata, thank you so much. I am new to jquery so i have one small question, how can i shift the tree icon to the right of the node. It is displayed on left side . I tried with obj.insertAfter( obj.childNodes[2],tmp); but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete solution with the icon to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/492/

The change from the original answer is this:

```
obj.appendChild(tmp);
```

Comment: there is one problem still: If i click on tree icon next to root node then the icon is displaced. It happens only with parent nodes not with child nodes. For child nodes the icon behave correctly.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry about that, here is the final working code: http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/493/

Comment: Thank you It works :) Just for learning purpose, what was the actual change ?

Comment: I replaced the `appendChild` with `insertBefore`, and the second parameter of the call is the 4th child of the node. If the child exists - it is the UL node of all children and the icon is inserted before the list, if it does not exist - the icon is appended at the end of the node.