# jstree custom node markup

Tags: javascript, jstree

Is there a way to have custom markup or add additional html elements to some of the nodes.

For example, we want to add an arrow (link) right after the node text for all the nodes under a path, and when user click on the arrow, open the context menu.
I know the context menu can be opened using the right click, but the requirement is to have an arrow after the node and clicking on the arrow should open the context menu.

Is there a way to customize or add additional html elements to selective tree nodes, and programmatically open the context menu or link click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is using a plugin, you can take a look at similar sample plugins here: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/src/misc.js (the questionmark plugin for example).

Here is a rough demo, modify as needed: http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/490/

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var img = document.createElement('IMG');
    img.src = "http://jstree.com/tree-icon.png";
    img.className = "jstree-contextmenubtn";

    $.jstree.plugins.contextmenubtn = function (options, parent) {
        this.bind = function () {
            parent.bind.call(this);
            this.element
                .on("click.jstree", ".jstree-contextmenubtn", $.proxy(function (e) {
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        $(e.target).closest('.jstree-node').children('.jstree-anchor').trigger('contextmenu');
                    }, this));
        };
        this.teardown = function () {
            this.element.find(".jstree-contextmenubtn").remove();
            parent.teardown.call(this);
        };
        this.redraw_node = function(obj, deep, callback, force_draw) {
            obj = parent.redraw_node.call(this, obj, deep, callback, force_draw);
            if(obj) {
                var tmp = img.cloneNode(true);
                obj.insertBefore(tmp, obj.childNodes[2]);
            }
            return obj;
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I looked at one of your answer on mailing list and i was looking at questionmark plugin, looked at your jsfiddle, this is exactly what I am looking for. However, there's one more thing that i cant figureout, it shows the image button for each node, however I need to show the imgbutton only for certrain nodes. Inside redraw_node how can i get the node, or original json data for the node ? so that i can conditionally do obj.insertBefore

Comment: Try logging out `console.log(this.get_node(obj));` before invoking the parent function (as the first line of the `redraw_node` function. It should be what you need.

Comment: how do i change the position / coordinates of the context menu ? @vakata

Comment: Set the `show_at_node` option to `false`: http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=show_at_node&f=$.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.show_at_node and when using `.trigger('contextmenu')` make sure you pass an event object with coordinates.

Answer (score 8):

With jstree version 3.3.0 you can use [node_customize plugin](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/3.3.0/src/misc.js#L400-L453)

```
$("#category-tree").jstree({
  core: {
    data: nodes
  },
  node_customize: {
    default: function(el, node) {
      $(el).find('a').append(arrowHtml)
    }
  },
  plugins: ['node_customize']
})
```

Comment: It seems this is not OOTB plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from server and render any structure before `jstree initialization`

```
<div id="tree">
  <ul>
  <li data-jstree='{"opened":true,"selected":true}'>
    opened <b>root node ></b>
      <ul>
        <li>default node</li>
        <li><b>badge</b> example: <span class="badge badge-warning" onclick="alert('clicked!')">clickme!</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li data-jstree='{"disabled":true}'>root 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

somewhere: `$('#tree').jstree();` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhydo25r/3/)